# Incorrect component operation after the AEM version upgrade

Tags: aem, aem-6

I ran into a specific issue in a component after upgrading from 6.3 to 6.5.6. The component has after which 1 of 3 options is selected, and depending on which value is selected, another field should be displayed. At 6.3 there are no problems with this, after the upgrade to 6.5 the field is no longer displayed. All this in the component dialog box. The component has not changed. I noticed that the style has "hide" and it should disappear, but it doesn't. We have AEM version 6.5.6. I installed 6.5 myself and tested it and the component works. Then I installed service pack 6.5.6 and the component stopped working. This is a problem in the service pack. But I don’t understand why.

[Incorrectly working component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rDJO.png)
[Сorrectly working component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZafZ.png)

In this case, the javascript file is connected. There are no errors in the logs.

dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:granite="http://www.adobe.com/jcr/granite/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          jcr:title="Box"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
          extraClientlibs="[app.site.campaign.email.box,app.site.campaign.email.dialog.paddingOptionsToggleable,app.site.campaign.email.dialog.scrollableTabs]">
    <content
            granite:class="cmp-box--editor"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <tabs
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/tabs">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <general
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            jcr:title="General"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns"
                            margin="{Boolean}true">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <column
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <boxLayout
                                            granite:class="cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide"
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
                                            fieldLabel="Box Layout"
                                            name="./boxLayout"
                                            text="Box Style">
                                        <granite:data
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-tab=".list-option-listfrom-showhide-tab"
                                                cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-target=".boxlayout-list-option-listfrom-showhide-target"/>
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <square
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Square"
                                                    value="square"/>
                                            <rectangle
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Rectangle"
                                                    value="rectangle"/>
                                            <flexibleHeight
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Flex"
                                                    value="flex"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </boxLayout>
                                    <hideOnView
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
                                            fieldLabel="Hide Box"
                                            name="./hideOnView">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <standard
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Always visible"
                                                    value=""/>
                                            <hideOnMobile
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Hide on mobile"
                                                    value="mobile-hide"/>
                                            <hideOnDesktop
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Hide on desktop"
                                                    value="desktop-hide mobile-show"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </hideOnView>
                                    <backgroundColor
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
                                            fieldLabel="Background Color"
                                            name="./backgroundColor">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <White
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="White"
                                                    value="#F8F8F8"/>
                                            <Black
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Black"
                                                    value="#191919"/>
                                            <Transparent
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    text="Transparent"
                                                    value="#242424"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </backgroundColor>
                                    <backgroundImage
                                            granite:class="hide boxlayout-list-option-listfrom-showhide-target foundation-layout-util-vmargin"
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                                        <granite:data
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                showhidetargetclearfields="img:./backgroundImage"
                                                showhidetargetvalue="square,rectangle"/>
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <file
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
                                                    allowUpload="{Boolean}false"
                                                    autoStart="{Boolean}false"
                                                    class="cq-droptarget"
                                                    fieldLabel="Background Image"
                                                    fileNameParameter="./bgFileName"
                                                    fileReferenceParameter="./bgFileReference"
                                                    mimeTypes="[image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png]"
                                                    multiple="{Boolean}false"
                                                    name="./backgroundImage"
                                                    title="Background Image"
                                                    uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
                                                    useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </backgroundImage>
                                    <boxLink
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathfield"
                                            name="./boxLink"
                                            required="false"
                                            fieldLabel="Hyperlink"
                                            rootPath="/content"/>
                                    <boxLinkSuffix
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/inputgroup"
                                            fieldLabel="Hyperlink suffix"
                                            renderReadOnly="{Boolean}true">
                                        <field
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                fieldLabel="Hyperlink suffix"
                                                name="./boxLinkSuffix"/>
                                        <rightButton
                                                class="coral-Button--square"
                                                icon="coral-Icon--adobeCampaign"
                                                init="acmetadatapicker"
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/button"
                                                targetinput="input[name='./boxLinkSuffix']"/>
                                    </boxLinkSuffix>
                                </items>
                            </column>
                        </items>
                    </general>
                </items>
            </tabs>
        </items>
        <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/tabs"
                type="nav"/>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

js

```
(function(document, $) {
    'use strict';
    // When dialog gets injected
    $(document).on('foundation-contentloaded', function(e) {
        $('.cmp-box--editor coral-select.cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide', e.target).each(function(i, element) {

            // Show or hide touch UI Dialog components
            var target = $(element).data('cqDialogDropdownShowhideTarget');

            if (target) {
                Coral.commons.ready(element, function(component) {
                    // If there is already an inital value make sure the according target element becomes visible
                    showHideTarget(component, target);

                    component.on('change', function() {
                        showHideTarget(component, target);
                    });
                });
            }

            // Show or hide touch UI Dialog Tabs
            var tab = $(element).data('cqDialogDropdownShowhideTab');
            var displaySiteLogo = $(".cmp-box--editor coral-checkbox[name='./logo/displaySiteLogo']");

            if (tab) {
                Coral.commons.ready(element, function(component) {
                    // If there is already an inital value make sure the according tab element becomes visible
                    showHideTab(component, tab);

                    component.on('change', function() {
                        showHideTab(component, tab);
                    });
                    $(displaySiteLogo).change(function() {
                        showHideTab(component, tab);
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        $('.cmp-box--editor coral-Checkbox.cq-dialog-checkbox-showhide', e.target).each(function(i, element) {

            // Show or hide touch UI Dialog components
            var target = $(element).data('cqDialogDropdownShowhideTarget');
            if (target) {
                Coral.commons.ready(element, function(component) {
                    // If there is already an inital value make sure the according target element becomes visible
                    showHideTarget(component, target, $(component).attr("checked"));

                    component.on('change', function(chEve) {
                        showHideTarget(component, target, chEve.currentTarget.checked);
                    });
                });
            }

        });

        showHideTarget($('.cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide', e.target));
        showHideTab($('.cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide', e.target));
    });

    /**
     * Show or hide touch UI Dialog components based on the selection made in the dropdown/select.
     *
     * @param {component} component - currently selected element.
     * @param {target} target - target elements.
     */
    function showHideTarget(component, target, checkedVal) {
        var value      = component.value,
            $component = $(component);
        if ($component.hasClass("coral-Checkbox")) {
            if (checkedVal)
                value = $component.data("checkboxTarget");
        }

        $(target).each(function(i, targetObj) {
            var targetValue = $(targetObj).data('showhidetargetvalue');
            var array = targetValue.split(',');

            $(targetObj).not('.hide').addClass('hide');
            if ($.inArray(value, array) === -1) {
                // Clear fields
                var clearFields = $(targetObj).data('showhidetargetclearfields');

                if (clearFields) {
                    showHideClearFields(clearFields);
                }
            } else {
                $(targetObj).filter("[data-showhidetargetvalue='" + targetValue + "']").removeClass('hide');
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Show or hide touch UI Dialog tabs based on the selection made in the dropdown/select.
     *
     * @param {component} component - Currently selected element.
     * @param {tab} tab - Tab elements.
     */
    function showHideTab(component, tab) {
        var value = component.value;

        $(tab).each(function(i, tabObj) {
            var $tab = $(tabObj).parents('.coral-Panel');
            var tabId = $tab.attr('aria-labelledby');
            var tabHead = $('.cmp-box--editor coral-tabview').find('coral-tab#' + tabId);
            var tabValue = $(tabObj).data('showhidetabvalue');

            var showHideTabValueArray = tabValue.split(',');

            $(tabHead).not('.hide').addClass('hide');
            $(tabObj).not('.hide').addClass('hide');

            // Check any target condition before show or hide tab
            var showtab = true;
            var customCondition = $(tabObj).data('customcondition');

            if (customCondition) {
                showtab = checkCustomCondition(value);
            }

            if ($.inArray(value, showHideTabValueArray) !== -1 && showtab) {
                $(tabHead).removeClass('hide');
                $(tabObj).filter("[data-showhidetabvalue='" + tabValue + "']").removeClass('hide');
            } else {
                // Clear fields
                var clearFields = $(tabObj).data('showhidetabclearfields');

                if (clearFields) {
                    showHideClearFields(clearFields);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Custom conditional checks.
     *
     * @param {string} value - Currently selected element.
     * @returns {boolean} - Element condition true or false.
     */
    function checkCustomCondition(value) {
        var conditionResult = true;
        var hideOverlayPosition;
        var $chkDisplaySiteLogo = $(".cmp-box--editor coral-checkbox[name='./logo/displaySiteLogo']");
        var $selBoxLayout = $(".cmp-box--editor input[name='./boxLayout']");
        var $selLogoPosition = $(".cmp-box--editor input[name='./logo/position']");

        switch (value) {
            case 'square':
                hideOverlayPosition = $chkDisplaySiteLogo.is('[checked]') && $selLogoPosition.attr('value') === 'leftMiddle';

                if (hideOverlayPosition) {
                    showHideOverlaySelection(true);
                } else {
                    showHideOverlaySelection(false);
                }

                conditionResult = !$chkDisplaySiteLogo.is('[checked]') || hideOverlayPosition;

                break;

            case 'leftMiddle':
                hideOverlayPosition = $selBoxLayout.attr('value') === 'square' && $chkDisplaySiteeLogo.is('[checked]');

                showHideOverlaySelection(hideOverlayPosition);

                conditionResult = !$chkDisplaySiteLogo.is('[checked]') || hideOverlayPosition;

                break;

            case 'topLeft':
            case 'topCenter':
            case 'topRight':
                showHideOverlaySelection(false);

                conditionResult = $selBoxLayout.attr('value') === 'square' && !$chkDisplaySiteLogo.is('[checked]');

                break;
        }

        return conditionResult;
    }

    /**
     * Hide/Un-hide overlay position selection elements.
     *
     * @param {boolean} hide - Hide or un-hide.
     */
    function showHideOverlaySelection(hide) {
        var $overlayPositionSelection = $(".cmp-box--editor coral-select[name='./overlay/overlayPosition']");

        if (hide) {
            var $hiddenInput = $overlayPositionSelection.find('input');

            $overlayPositionSelection
                .find('coral-selectlist-item')
                .filter('[value!="bottomRight"]')
                .not('.hide')
                .addClass('hide');

            $hiddenInput
                .attr('name', './overlay/overlayPosition')
                .attr('value', 'bottomRight');

            $overlayPositionSelection.find('span.coral3-Select-label').text('Bottom Right');
        } else {
            $overlayPositionSelection.find('coral-selectlist-item').removeClass('hide');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clear touch UI Dialog fields based on the selection made in the dropdown/select.
     *
     * @param {Array} clearFields - Array of field type and field names in format {<fieldType>:<fieldName>}.
     *          Fields supported: checkbox, textfield, image (fileupload).
     */
    function showHideClearFields(clearFields) {
        var fieldsArray = [];

        if (clearFields.indexOf(',') === -1) {
            fieldsArray.push(clearFields);
        } else {
            fieldsArray = clearFields.split(',');
        }

        fieldsArray.forEach(function(field) {
            if (field.indexOf(':') !== -1) {
                var delimiter = field.lastIndexOf(':');
                var inputType = field.substring(0, delimiter);
                var inputName = field.substring(delimiter + 1);

                if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
                    clearCheckBox(inputName);
                } else if (inputType === 'textfield') {
                    clearTextField(inputName);
                } else if (inputType === 'img') {
                    clearImage(inputName);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Uncheck checkbox.
     *
     * @param {string} name - Checkbox input name.
     */
    function clearCheckBox(name) {
        $(".cmp-box--editor coral-checkbox[name='" + name + "']").removeAttr('checked');
    }

    /**
     * Reset textfield to empty.
     *
     * @param {string} name - Textfield input name.
     */
    function clearTextField(name) {
        $(".cmp-box--editor input[name='" + name + "']").attr('value', '');
    }

    /**
     * Delete fileupload image.
     *
     * @param {string} name - Image input name.
     */
    function clearImage(name) {
        var $imgInput         = $(".cmp-box--editor input[name='" + name + "']"),
            $imgInputParent   = $imgInput.parents('.coral-FileUpload--dropSupport').parent(),
            $imgFileName      = $imgInputParent.find('input.cq-FileUpload-filename'),
            $imgFileReference = $imgInputParent.find('input.cq-FileUpload-filereference'),
            $imgFileDelete    = $imgInputParent.find('input.cq-FileUpload-filedelete');

        $imgInput.attr('value', '');

        $imgInputParent.find('.cq-FileUpload-thumbnail-img').remove();

        if ($imgFileName.length > 0) {
            $imgFileName.attr('value', '');
            $imgFileName.removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        if ($imgFileReference.length > 0) {
            $imgFileReference.attr('value', '');
            $imgFileReference.removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        if ($imgFileDelete.length > 0) {
            $imgFileDelete.attr('value', 'true');
            $imgFileDelete.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }

}(document, Granite.$));
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may need to show the dialog.xml file of your component for us to understand better. If you're using other libraries (e.g. ACS commons), it might have compatibility issues with the Service Pack

Comment: Yes of course. I have attached the dialog and listener code. I removed tabs from the dialog code that are not needed. Left only the problematic one.

Comment: Any ideas? I don't know where to look anymore.